# As a cricketer what kind of Exercise i should be avoiding working out in the gym?

Tags: exercise

Do heavy and bulky muscles restrict range of motion?

Comment: There's no movement that will lower your range of motion. Only bad practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to worry about avoiding any exercises. Unless you're doing serious bodybuilding, you'd normally just gain overall fitness and strength; not large bulky muscles which will hinder your range of movement.